# String with accent (´`~^) output with error

Tags: string, file, text, bots, autohotkey

I'm making a bot where the user selects a .txt file, and the bot reads the file, but when he sends the string to a notepad for example, the characters with accents come out with an error.

Exemple: "São Paulo" in the file come out "SÃ@o Paulo".

I'm using AutoHotKey 2.0.

```
FileSelectFile, list_polo
FileReadLine, polo, %list_polo%, %A_Index%
ControlSend, , %polo%, notepad.exe
```

Comment: [Save the .ahk file with UTF-8 BOM encoding](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#nonascii)